# Drools 6.4 KieScanner how to specify what what Maven repo to use

Tags: maven, drools, kie

I am new to Drools and am trying to use KieScanner to do hot swap of my rules. I have read the documentation and the discussions around this subject. I am not clear on a few things. The following code snippet is straight from Drools 6.4 documentation:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId( "org.acme", "myartifact", "1.0-SNAPSHOT" );
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer( releaseId );
KieScanner kScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner( kContainer );
```

1. How do I tell the code what maven repository to use?
2. What are the artifacts that goes into the jar file? Rule files, plus pojo changes. Anything else?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. By default it will use the standard Maven settings hierarchy (system, user, ...), unless you specify a custom Maven settings file.

For this, you can reference [the documentation chapter 4.2.3.5 "Settings.xml and Remote Repository Setup"](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e3037):

> The settings.xml file can be located in 3 locations, the actual
>   settings used is a merge of those 3 locations.
>
> - The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> - A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
> - Folder location specified by the system property kie.maven.settings.custom
>
> The settings.xml is used to specify the location of remote repositories.

Personally, I find very helpful to specify to the KieScanner a custom Maven settings file via the system property `kie.maven.settings.custom`, because normally I have my KJAR artifacts and Jar of the "model" only in a custom internal repository (and not on public repo or Maven central).

2. The KJAR should be simply a new release of the previous [KJAR](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIEModuleIntroductionBuildingIntroductionSection).

I think meaningful here to highlight what is my personal common pitfall with hot-swap rules... Be aware [drools incremental compilation works at resources level](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1087?focusedCommentId=13188640&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13188640), so if a rule should not re-trigger after the hot-swap, either make sure you have guarding condition on the LHS that will naturally ensure that will be guaranteed, or either you should keep those unmodified rules isolated in their own resources(/files).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I just have a quick follow up question on this. The KJAR are the rules and the POJOS(models) referenced in the rules correct?

Comment: while you can definitely put the POJOs for the Model within the same (KJAR) artifact, I think it is encourage for them to be a separate JAR, for example a separate Maven dependency. This way, you can reuse the model across several KJARs, or other code bases not strictly related to Drools. Personally, this is also my preferred option, the only occasional times I "embed" the model within a KJAR is when I'm starting on a new domain, so just easier to get it started all in one place and then refactor it properly before any further evolution/stabilization work.

Comment: Or does it include the KieContainter and KieSession. I wish there were more examples on this. It is difficult for me to follow dry documentation without working examples. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No, strictly speaking, a `KJAR` does not `contains` the `KieContainer` nor the `KieSession`. The `KJAR` is a packaging container while the others are runtime objects. A `KieContainer` is the runtime object representation of the `KJAR`. A `KieBase` within a `KieContainer` is a set of rules (in binary form) from the `KJAR`. There can be several sets each with different rules. And a `KieSession` is an instance of a drools session to execute the rules (it has a reference the the `KieBase` used to construct the session and references to the facts which are POJOs).

Comment: @Adriank can we mark this as answered if it indeed answered the original question about _Drools 6.4 KieScanner how to specify what what Maven repo to use_, please?
It would be easier to follow separate questions, separately.
Quick comment about "_It is difficult for me to follow dry documentation without working examples._" personally I've found the [Examples section of the doc](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIEExamplesSection) to cover every possible combo, w/ working examples which can be checked out and run locally from github? Hope that helps